# How to fix [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] when making a DELETE request in Node

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a posts route where people can make add comments to a post. Im adding the ability target the unique ID of the post to delete it. The post gets deleted but something gets called again and i believe when it checks, the post doesn't exist anymore and returns with an error. Where in my code could it be calling twice?

I then check to see if its deleted on the database and it has been.

I am learning mongoose and routing but the logic looks sound? but do correct me if im missing something.

Im using Postman to test the back end logic. Tried two different users, but the result is the same.

My code:

```
// @route   DELETE api/posts/:ID
// @desc    Delete post
// @access  private
router.delete("/:id", passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false}), (req, res) => {
    Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id})
        .then(profile => {
            Post.findById(req.params.id)
                .then(post => {
                    //Check for post owner
                    if(post.user.toString() !== req.user.id){
                            return res.status(401).json({notauthorised: "User not authorised"});
                    }                       
                    // Delete
                    post.remove().then(() => {
                        console.log("Success 1")
                        return res.json({success: true})

                    });      
                })
                .catch(err = res.status(404).json({postnotfound: "No post found"}))
        })
})
```

The console error message:

```
Success 1
(node:5228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Google Drive\Test Lab\Projects\mernTutorial\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Google Drive\Test Lab\Projects\mernTutorial\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\Google Drive\Test Lab\Projects\mernTutorial\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at post.remove.then (D:\Google Drive\Test Lab\Projects\mernTutorial\routes\api\posts.js:83:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:5228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with
.catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5228) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is what leading me to think something gets called twice because the Success 1 message appears at the end and then the error.

I expect when a post is deleted, it to respond to the user with a json string, {success: true} but i recieve in postman {postnotfound: "No post found"}

Comment: You are missing catch blocks for **findOne()** and **remove()** methods, add them and try logging errors in there.. you will get to know where exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only apparent thing that I can see that could be the root cause of your error is,

```
   .catch(err = res.status(404).json({postnotfound: "No post found"}))
```

You are trying to declare a variable inside the parameter of a catch block I believe this is incorrect, however, you could have an arrow function inside of a catch parameter, I believe that is the catch in this snippet of code.

Comment: Im bloody daft, I have just tested that by turning that into an arrow function and it worked as expected. Thank you for being another pair of eyes!